# Install ant libraries on an Oracle Java 7 installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, ant

I was getting started on LibreOffice development and this [link](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Native_Build) said to do `sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice` and then do a `git clone`. Now, build-dep installs openJDK and I already have Oracle Java installed. I cloned the repo, ran `./autogen.sh` and was installing dependencies manually whenever it complained. It complained ant was missing, so I used the information on this [link](http://genealo.org/wiki/How_to_install_Oracle_Java/JDK_on_Ubuntu_12.04) and got ant installed. Now, the script is complaining that I don't have ant libraries and I am at my wits' end how to install it. Please help!

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like your ANT_HOME path is not set perhaps?

try at the terminal:

```
echo $ANT_HOME
```

if nothing displays, then you are not set.

try:

```
export ANT_HOME=/path/to/your/ant/install
```